# How to create a required many-to-many relationship in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, join, data-integrity

Suppose I have a schema like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Artist (
  ArtistID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ArtistName TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ArtistID)
);

CREATE TABLE Song (
  SongID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SongTitle TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (SongID)
);

CREATE TABLE SongArtist (
  SongID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ArtistID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (SongID, ArtistID),
  FOREIGN KEY (SongID) REFERENCES Song(SongID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artist(ArtistID)
);
```

By defining a column as `NOT NULL` I can semantically say that having a value in it is **required.** How would I make a many-to-many relationship required, but only in **one direction?**

In this situation, what I mean is this: How can I say that a `Song` row must have **at least one** `Artist` row associated with it through the `SongArtist` join table? If I were to represent a song as the `JSON` object below, this would be equivalent to saying that the `songArtistIds` array **must have a length of 1 or higher.**

```
{
  songId: 745194,
  songTitle: "Title",
  songArtistIds: [523214]
}
```

However, an `Artist` row need not be associated with any `Song` row necessarily. An artist can have 0 or more songs, but a song **must have 1 or more artists.** How can I enforce this in SQLite? Also, if the answer is that I cannot do this in SQLite, then what alternative do I have for an embedded application?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to ensure there's one "SongArtist" record for every "Song" record.  If that's correct then what you want cannot be done in the schema with a constraint of any kind.

Comment: What would be the best way to ensure that such a relationship exists, then? Periodically running some kind of external data validation against the database? How would an experienced database design handle such a problem?

Comment: Yes, a separate validation process is probably the best you can do, at least with a schema as you've shown.